# Xcode example of universal .app with assembly intel .s file and arm .s file

Tags: xcode, assembly, interface-builder, universal

Xcode example of universal .app with assembly intel .s file and arm .s file.
I how how to build a command tool with "lipo" but I need to build application with project builder and IB.
Any URL will be greatly appreciate.

Xcode universal example project with assembly file